# SQL Server insert trigger not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert

This is my first time using triggers.

My trigger is not being triggered please help.

```
CREATE TRIGGER sbhack_autoban
ON LOG_CONNECT201211
FOR INSERT
AS
  BEGIN
      /* query to run if single or multiple data is 
       inserted into LOG_CONNECT201211 table */
      UPDATE login.dbo.USER_CHECK_LOGIN
      SET    login.dbo.USER_CHECK_LOGIN.CHECKLOGIN = 2
      WHERE  login.dbo.USER_CHECK_LOGIN.USER_KEY IN 
              (SELECT e.USER_KEY
                 FROM   game.dbo.CHAR_DATA0 AS e
                        INNER JOIN gamelogs.dbo.LOG_USING_DEPOT201211 AS p
                          ON e.CHAR_KEY = p.CHAR_KEY
                 WHERE  p.GATENUM = 150)
             AND login.dbo.USER_CHECK_LOGIN.CHECKLOGIN = 0
             AND login.dbo.USER_CHECK_LOGIN.USER_KEY != 51;
  END
```

This is suppose to run the query inside the BEGIN : END if an entry is inserted into the `LOG_CONNECT201211` table. But nothing is happening even when I have inserted multiple data into `LOG_CONNECT201211`.

Comment: Your trigger isn't referencing `INSERTED`  is that intentional?

Comment: It seems odd that you're not referencing the `Inserted` pseudo-table anywhere in your trigger.... you're basically upgrading **everything** - not just the rows that were in fact inserted....

Comment: Uhmmm, Sorry but this is my first time using triggers. Can you please tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Your trigger should do something **based on the rows inserted** - which are available in the `Inserted` pseudo table in your trigger. This one here just updates that other table ALL THE time and doesn't take into account / doesn't use any of the information from the rows that have been inserted.... So the question is: if you insert 10 new rows - what exactly do you want to do with those, in your trigger? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Something like a condition? Can you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: I just want the query to run if a new row is inserted to that table. thats all.

Comment: When your `INSERT` trigger fires - then at least one new row **has been** inserted! That's a fact. Now the question is: given that a single or multiple new rows have been inserted - what do you want to do??

Comment: I want to run the query.

Comment: Am i looking at this wrong? Is trigger not the thing for me?

Answer (score 1):

When your `INSERT` trigger fires - then at least one new row **has been** inserted! That's a fact.

Now the question is: given that a single or multiple new rows have been inserted - **what** do you want to do with this knowledge??

Typically, you could e.g. set a column to a value you cannot specify as a default constraint - or you could insert the fact that the row has been inserted into an audit table or something....

So you'd have something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sbhack_autoban
ON LOG_CONNECT201211
FOR INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO LogAudit(InsertedDate, UserKey)
        SELECT 
             GETDATE(), i.User_Key
        FROM
             Inserted i
```

or something like that....

**Update:** ok, so you want to run that `UPDATE` statement when the rows have been inserted - not 100% clear, what columns/values from the inserted rows you want to use - looks like the `e.UserKey` column only - correct?

Then the `UPDATE` would be:

```
UPDATE login.dbo.USER_CHECK_LOGIN
SET login.dbo.USER_CHECK_LOGIN.CHECKLOGIN = 2
WHERE  
   login.dbo.USER_CHECK_LOGIN.USER_KEY IN 
          (SELECT USER_KEY FROM Inserted)
   AND login.dbo.USER_CHECK_LOGIN.CHECKLOGIN = 0
   AND login.dbo.USER_CHECK_LOGIN.USER_KEY != 51;
```

**Update #2:**

The point I still **don't understand** is : why do you want to run an update that uses the `USER_CHECK_LOGIN`, `CHAR_DATA0` and `LOG_USING_DEPOT201211` tables, when some rows are getting inserted into a totally separate, unrelated table `LOG_CONNECT201211` ??

A trigger is used when you want to do something **because rows have been inserted** into that table - but in that case, you typically want to do something **with the rows and their values** that have been inserted...

I just don't see any connection between the *rows being inserted into `LOG_CONNECT201211`* event, and the tables you are then querying from and updating. Where's the link?? ***WHY*** do you need to run **this `UPDATE`* when data is inserted into `LOG_CONNECT201211` ?? It would make sense if data where inserted into one of the tables *involved in the `UPDATE`* - but like this, it just totally doesn't make any sense .....

Comment: Yes, I want that if a row is inserted into the LOG_CONNECT201211 the update query will be triggered. hows that done?

Comment: @user1553142: so **what columns/values** from the inserted rows do you want to use in your `UPDATE` query?

Comment: Hmmmmm. I think I'm doing this wrong, I don't want anything from the inserted rows.

Comment: @user1553142: in that case, an INSERT trigger is definitely the wrong way to go !

Comment: @user1553142: I would need to know when and what exactly you're trying to do - still not clear....

Comment: I think I'll just make this a query that will run every minute between a time frame. is that possible?

Comment: like, run every minute or every 5min from 8AM to 10AM, then 12PM to 2PM, then 4PM to 6PM so on... Is that possible.

Comment: @user1553142: sure you can do that - but ***WHY***?!?!? If nothing changes in the tables involved in that UPDATE - what point is there in running that UPDATE again and again and again?? You need to run this UPDATE when **something changes in the tables involved** in this `UPDATE` !

Comment: The thing is the log tables contain the information on violations, if a user has violations, when he logsout he will then be banned.

Comment: So, check the log if the user has violation, if the logout log has a new insert then check if its a user that has a violation, if its a user that has a violation, update the users permission to NONE or BAN.

Comment: so what do you think sir? :)

Comment: @user1553142: I think you need to rearchitect your solution. You need to determine **when** something changes that has an effect on the user's violation. Only when something relevant **changes** should you run that `UPDATE` statement - don't just execute this over and over and over again - that's not a good design ...